# where android quiz applications store data

Tags: java, android

I am new to android trying to develop a quiz app. want to know where can  store questions and answers ,because there is an option for auto updating questions daily.storing **DB or File** which one is better ?thank you for your replay

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I always go for DB, it takes a bit more time to set up but once it's set up it makes things a lot easier and in my opinion has way more pros than cons. Though you can do a bit of research to get a comparison.

If you're not going to have a lot of data in your database then you could store in a file for simplicity but I still prefer the DB option and there's plenty of guides and advice on how to implement them out there.